# JavaScript - Drawing a simple 15x10 map from a 400-element array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

So I recently switched my map from Map Tiler (or something) to Tiled. The original map tiler gave me multple arrays (for each level of the X axis) whereas Tiled returns the map in one long array.

So I would simply do,

```
      for (var y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= 0; x++) {
// draw map board[0][13] for example
// then tileX *32 and tileY *32 being the spritesheet being cut
context.drawImage(imageObj, tileX * 32, tileY * 32, 32, 32, x*32, y*32, 32, 32)
}
}
```

And now I am having a hard time drawing a simple map using the long array.

My tileset: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkU1c.png, what it would look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drh5Z.png

Question is, how would you go about trying to get the current 15x10 required arrays from that 400-element array all while trying to paint it across a canvas?

```js
// Viewport of canvas is 15 tiles wide, 10 tiles tall
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')

var imageObj = new Image()
imageObj.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkU1c.png'

var client = {
    'vWidth': 15,
        'vHeight': 10,
        'imageWidth': 159,
        'imageHeight': 32
}



var tilesX = client.ImageWidth / 32
var tilesY = client.ImageHeight / 32

// Get the correct 15x10 canvas from a single 400-element array
// Map should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drh5Z.png

imageObj.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0)
    
    var getTile = 0

    for (var y = 0; y <= client.vHeight; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= client.vWidth; x++) {

            // Somehow as you go thru the canvas on every x,y of (15x10)... 
            // there has to be a way to getting the correct tile of the map
            // starting from 0,0... so once every 15 loops [client.vWidth] (for painting of map), on the BOARD...
            // skip 20 array elements and THEN start painting from where you last left off

            // Get the correct tile
            var tile = (board()[getTile])

            // For positioning on canvas
            var theX = x * 32
            var theY = y * 32


            var tileY = Math.floor(tile / tilesX)
            var tileX = Math.floor(tile % tilesX)

            console.log('Tile: ' + tile + ', TileY: ' + tileY + ', TileX: ' + tileX)

            context.drawImage(imageObj, tileX * 32, tileY * 32, 32, 32, theX, theY, 32, 32)

            getTile++
        }
    }
}

function board() {
    return [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
}

//console.log(board);
```

```css
#canvas {
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="352" width="512"></canvas>
```

This reference image will help. This is what I'm trying to accomplish from that long `board()` array.

[image]

What I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/3fx58ock/

Comment: So you just want to get the correct tile index? Like `y * client.vWidth + x `?

Comment: If your map was 15x10, why does your array have 400 elements and not 150?

Comment: @rrowland Because the viewport is 15x10 and the map is 20x20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @J4G mentioned in his comment, you can multiply `y` by the width to find the row's offset in the 1D array and add `x` to find the column's offset from that:

```
function drawViewport(leftBound, topBound) {
  var rightBound = leftBound + width;
  var bottomBound = topBound + height;

  for (var x = leftBound; x < rightBound; x++) {
    for (var y = topBound; y < bottomBound; y++) {
      map[x][y] = tiles[y*height + x]; // Plug your real code in here
    }
  }
}
```

`drawViewport(0,0)` would drop the top left of the map. `drawViewPort(2,2)` would draw the 15x10 area 2 down and 2 right from the top left of the map.

To explain, imagine a 2D array:

```
[ [a, b, c],
  [d, e, f] ]
```

As a 1D array, this would be:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Take `e`, which is in index 4. The width of the 2D array is 3.

```
var x = index%width;
// x = 4%3
// x = 1
```

Now that we have x, we can get y by dividing by width:

```
var y = (index-x)/width;
// y = 3/3;
// y = 1;
```

Therefore `1dArray[4] === 2dArray[1][1]`.

We can apply the inverse to `2dArray` to find the element's position in the 1D array:

```
var x = 1, y = 1;
var index = y*width + x;
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something along those lines. This totally makes sense... but the image still comes out bad in the end. But here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/3fx58ock/ (not quite there.)